# Relationship between graph expansion and conductance

Tags: graphs, reference-request, combinatorics, expanders

I'm quite confused about the exact relationship between the expansion of a graph and its conductance. My first question is:

- Could someone point me to a reference that discusses *both* of these notions? (I've found various lecture notes on related topics but these seem to focus either on expansion *or* on conductance...)

I've read that the expansion of $G$ is a measure for the speed of mixing of a random walk on $G$, i.e., the time for getting close to the stationary distribution. For a $d$-regular graph with constant expansion, for example, the mixing time is $\Theta(\log n)$. The same seems to be true for the conductance $\Phi(G)$, i.e., if $\Phi(G)$ is constant, then a random walk on $G$ will also mix in $\Theta(\log n)$ time. Moreover, this property of conductance holds even in non-regular graphs, and, for $d$-regular graphs the expansion of $G$ can be found by simply dividing the conductance of $G$ by $d$. This begs the following question:

- Why should we consider the expansion of a graph $G$, when the conductance seems to be a stronger measure (that subsumes expansion)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several different definitions for the expansion of a graph, but all of them are spatial. One common definition defined the expansion $h(G)$ of a graph $G$ as $$ h(G) = \min_{|S| \leq |G|/2} \frac{|\partial S|}{|S|}, $$
where $S$ is a set of vertices containing at most half of the vertices, and $\partial S$ is the *(edge) boundary* of $S$, the number of edges connecting $S$ to $\overline{S}$. For a $d$-regular connected graph, there is a strong connection between $h(G)$ and a spectral parameter, the *eigenvalue gap* $\lambda(G)$, which is the smallest non-zero eigenvalue of the Laplacian. For a $d$-regular connected graph, *Cheeger's inequality* states that
$$ \frac{\lambda(G)}{2} \leq h(G) \leq \sqrt{2d\lambda(G)}.  $$
This is often put in terms of the second largest eigenvalue $\lambda_2(G)$ of the adjacency matrix of $G$, which satisfies $\lambda_2(G) = d - \lambda(G)$. There must be versions of Cheeger's inequality for non-regular graphs, and I'll let you look them up.

A lot of information on expander graphs can be found in the survey (based on course notes) [Expander graphs and their applications](http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~nati/PAPERS/expander_survey.pdf) by Hoori, Linial and Wigderson. Other information is scattered among lecture notes and even recent papers.